# What's the equivalent of "MP4Box -hint" in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4box

I currently run my ffmpeg command to record the video then afterwards run `MP4Box -hint file.mp4` to make the file stream quicker for the web. Is there any way for ffmpeg to "hint" my file straightaway without the extra step?

Comment: What's your ffmpeg command-line? In the last GPAC version you can run most of FFmpeg internally. Since GPAC is your final step, that would better preserve the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-movflags +rtphint` as an output option.